# How do I deserialize json so that some json properties gets assigned to an array or List?

Tags: c#, json.net

Using Json.Net, how do I deserialize the following json to the OrderDepthFeed class provided below? I want the bid1 to go into Bid[0], bid2 into Bid[1] and so on.

```
{
    "i": "101",
    "m": 11,
    "tick_timestamp": 1440479701986,
    "bid1": 78.00,
    "bid_volume1": 60,
    "bid_orders1": 1,
    "ask1": 80.50,
    "ask_volume1": 500,
    "ask_orders1": 1,
    "bid2": 77.50,
    "bid_volume2": 500,
    "bid_orders2": 1,
    "ask2": 82.00,
    "ask_volume2": 1560,
    "ask_orders2": 2,
    "bid3": 77.00,
    "bid_volume3": 107,
    "bid_orders3": 2,
    "ask3": 82.95,
    "ask_volume3": 75,
    "ask_orders3": 1,
    "bid4": 76.30,
    "bid_volume4": 200,
    "bid_orders4": 1,
    "ask4": 83.40,
    "ask_volume4": 49,
    "ask_orders4": 1,
    "bid5": 76.00,
    "bid_volume5": 506,
    "bid_orders5": 2,
    "ask5": 83.50,
    "ask_volume5": 1500,
    "ask_orders5": 1
}
```

--

```
public class OrderDepthFeed {
    public int I { get; set; }
    public int M { get; set; }
    public int TickTimestamp { get; set; }

    public double?[] Ask { get; set; }
    public int?[] AskVolume { get; set; }
    public double?[] Bid { get; set; }
    public int?[] BidVolume { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the code I use, and the PascalCaseContractResolver only changes the case and removes underscores in property names by overriding ResolvePropertyName();

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new PascalCaseContractResolver();
var orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderDepthFeed>(json, serializerSettings);
```

Comment: Don't use `List<OrderDepthFeed>` because you have no array in your json.

Comment: Secondly, your `OrderDepthFeed` class not looking correct. Use `DataMember` to assign actual names and why `Ask`, `AskVolume` etc. are arrays?

Comment: I suppose changing the serialization so that `bidVolume` is an actual json array is not an option?

Comment: @X-TECH Because of the way I need to use the `Ask`, `AskVolume` in the application, it's much more useful having them as arrays.

Comment: You need to create a custom json converter for your type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a custom converter:

```
public class JsonOrderDepthFeedConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //implement this if you want to convert to json in the same way
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var order = JObject.Load(reader);
        var orderDepthFeed = new OrderDepthFeed
        {
            I = order["i"].Value<int>(),
            M = order["m"].Value<int>(),
            TickTimestamp = order["tick_timestamp"].Value<long>()
        };

        const int count = 5;
        orderDepthFeed.Ask = new double?[count];
        orderDepthFeed.AskVolume = new int?[count];
        orderDepthFeed.Bid = new double?[count];
        orderDepthFeed.BidVolume = new int?[count];

        for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            JToken aux;

            if (order.TryGetValue("ask" + i, out aux)) orderDepthFeed.Ask[i - 1] = aux.Value<double>();
            if (order.TryGetValue("ask_volume" + i, out aux)) orderDepthFeed.AskVolume[i - 1] = aux.Value<int>();
            if (order.TryGetValue("bid" + i, out aux)) orderDepthFeed.Bid[i - 1] = aux.Value<double>();
            if (order.TryGetValue("bid_volume" + i, out aux)) orderDepthFeed.BidVolume[i - 1] = aux.Value<int>();
        }

        return orderDepthFeed;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(OrderDepthFeed) == objectType;
    }
}
```

and how you use it:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new JsonOrderDepthFeedConverter() } };
var order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderDepthFeed>(json, settings);
```

Comment: In fact, there is no need for a JsonConverter. You can write a method with what you do in `ReadJson` and return the `orderDepthFeed`.

Comment: @Eser for just this one case, yes you can. But if you have a List of them or a more complex data structure that contains an OrderDepthFeed, this is the way to do it, because you write small, reusable converters for the custom bits and the rest just works.

Comment: Andrew, I know what it is, how to write it. As I said, this question doesn't require it.

Answer (score -1):

Write your own `JsonConverter` so as to have complete control over (de)serialization. Create a class that derives from `JsonConverter`, and override the following methods: `CanConvert`, `ReadJson` and `WriteJson`.